# React Native - Timer function is not working if init inside the bridge class

Tags: ios, react-native

I was working on a iPhone app developed using the React Native framework. And some of the functions are implemented using Swift and called by the native bridge class.

Utilities swift is one of the bridge class and invoking a upload queue class. The upload queue will fire every 30 seconds.

Utilities.swift:

```
@objc func doPostSignInRoutine(username: String, callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) -> Void {
    UploadXfdfManager.start()
}
```

UploadXfdfManager.swift:

```
func start() {
   timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(self.scheduledTimer, target:self, selector: Selector("startUploadQueue"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

The timer function "startUploadQueue" is not fired if I invoke the queue inside the Utilities.swift, but it works perfectly if the queue is invoked outside the Utilities.swift. Any ideas of how to fix this problem? Please advise. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the native module is not running on a main thread. That's why the timer won't work in the native bridge class.

The problem can be fixed easily using the main thread calling the timer function

```
@objc func doPostSignInRoutine(username: String, callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) -> Void {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      UploadXfdfManager.start()
    }
}
```